# DexIndexOverflowException after moving to Android Studio 2.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I have just moved my project to Android Studio 2.2 and I am unable to generate my apk.

I got this error message :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

What should I do to remove this error ?

Comment: Are you using proguard´s minify feature? If not, do you still get this error if you enable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project compilation generate dex file, dex can handle until 65536 methods.

Your project compilation has over than 65536 methods, so you should **improve dependencies** or **enable MultiDex**, to split your code in more dex files

Take a look here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html better approach to solve it in your case.

Answer (score 3):

The number of method references in your project is more than 65536, which is the maximum number that can exist in one dex file. In this case, you should declare your application of type MultiDex, in the following steps :

1- Add the multidex dependency to your app level `build.gradle` :

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

2- Enable the multidex in your defaultConfigs in the app level build.gradle :

```
android {

defaultConfig {
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
   }
...
}
```

3- Define a new class MyApplication which extends MultidexApplication, which will serve as the entry point of your application.

```
public class MyApplication extends MultidexApplication
```

4- Finally, you should declare this new class in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.package.name">

<application
    android:name=".path-to.MyApplication">
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```